# Сохранение рекордов в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Я работаю над гоночной симуляцией между двумя роботами, которые управляются с джойстиков. Я написал приложение в окне pygame для фиксирования времени круга, то есть за сколько роботы  проехали три круга, и время для каждого свое.

У меня есть конечное время `self.final_time` (оно есть в примере кода) и `self.final_time_2` для второго робота. Они выводятся на экран, когда роботы заканчивают последний круг.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу сделать таблицу рекордов для каждого времени? Чтобы этот конечный результат сохранялся для каждого робота, и игрок мог после гонки ввести свое имя и сохранить результат, а потом при нажатии какой-нибудь кнопки посмотреть на лидеров, то есть чтобы была сортировка. Я видел примеры, что это делается с помощью словарей или shelve pack, но не могу понять до конца как конкретно на моем примере это сделать.

```
def finish_line(self):
    if self.check_number_markers:
        if self.start_strength_line.contains(self.robot_pos_1_point):
            if self.finish_line_count < self.checkpoint_count:
                self.finish_line_count += 1

            elif self.finish_line_count == self.checkpoint_count and self.finish_line_count == 3:
                if self.final_time is None:
                    self.final_time = time.time() - self.time_circle_robot_1
                self.robot_1.controlling_allowed = False
                self.player_1 = True

примерно те же строчки для второго робота, где self.final_time_2
вот что я попытался сделать со словарем, но не понимаю правильно ли это и вообще тут далеко до конца:

def highscore_read(self):
    content = ""
    with open("highscore.txt", 'r') as time:
        content = time.read()
    time = content.split(',')
    for names in time:
        I = names.split(":")
        self.d_highscore[I[0]] = [I[1], I[2]]
    return self.d_highscore
def highscore_write(self):
    f = open("highscore", 'w')
    to_write = ""
    for name in ('high', 'mid', 'low'):
        to_write += name
        to_write += ':'
        to_write += str(self.final_time.get(name)[0])
        to_write += ':'
        to_write += str(self.final_time.get(name)[1])
        to_write += ','
    print(to_write)
    to_write = to_write[:-1]
    f.write(to_write)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну у вас слишком сложно, думаю. В простейших случаях пользуйтесь `shelve`, а посложнее - какой-то базой данных.
Запись (предполагаю, что хранить потребуется что-то еще, так что в словарь "верхнего" уровня кладем один ключ - 'hi_scores':

```
import shelve
db = shelve.open(r'F:\TestPython\SHELVE\db')
scores = {'a': [1, 21.2], 'b': (2, 44.5)}
db['hi_scores'] = scores
db.close()
```

Чтение:

```
db = shelve.open(r'F:\TestPython\SHELVE\db')
d = db['hi_scores']
db.close()
```

P.S.

1. Рекомендую вызывать sync() после изменений - у меня база "разваливалась" как-то, когда исключене вылетало.
2. Используйте with, как в документации по `shelve`, может, тогда и проблем с исключениями не будет.